# knockoutjs - distinguish click event on button that get binding from 2 view model

Tags: knockout.js

I have two nested div and 2 button inside each div:

```
<div id="d1">
    <button data-bind="click:x">
        invoke x
    </button>
    <div id="d2">
        <button id="Q_btn" data-bind="click:x">
            invoke x
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and 2 view model that binding as:

```
var viewModel1 = {
    x : function() {
        alert('from model1')
    }
}

var viewModel2 = {
    x : function() {
        alert('from model2')
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel2, document.getElementById('d2'));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, document.getElementById('d1'));
```

Now when i click on button inside d2 (Q_btn), 2 alert raise, the first one says 'from mode2' and the second one says 'from model1'.
i want when i click on Q_btn only the first alert happen.

Note: in my project i load some html page on divs. each div has own view model. til now everythings are OK (each div work with own viewmodel and no conflict happen) but in case of nested div the above problem were occurred.

i appreciate your help

Comment: ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, document.getElementById('d1')); will bind to the outer div, and bind both buttons to viewmodel1

Comment: can't you return false; from the first alert (model2) to prevent bubbling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's any way of doing what you want in the way that you are suggesting. I'd recommend that you look at implementing a publisher/subscriber pattern here, either rolling your own (using something like [jquery.pubsub](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js)), or there's an extension called [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/) you could use.

This would enable you to have your view models nicely decoupled, yet allow them to talk to each other.

Comment: knockout-postbox can solve my issue. i use stopbinding to prevent binding from parent to child, then use puplishon and subscribeto to propagate the changes from child to parent view model.

Comment: Well, technically, you can thank @RPNiemeyer as he wrote the plug-in! Glad my answer pointed you in the right direction though.